# How to get DFT from Sound/Audio/Image?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, image-processing, fourier-analysis, sound

When I'm trying to do Discrete Fourier Transform or just get a ListPlot of values from Sound object, I get error message..
I understand that Fourier command (and ListPlot of course) works only with lists. May be there is some command to extract values from Sound/Audio/Image object so further I could apply DFT?

p.s.: it's interestingly though that similar transforms like Wavelet could be applied directly on image or sound samples...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you make a MWE of what you tried?

Comment: I'd like to apply Fourier to an image as easyly as ImagePeriodogram can be applied :)
But it's occured to me just now that we can use Sqrt@ImagePeriodogram, so we can get magnitude of Fourier spectrum :)
Periodogram is just an modulus of Fourier squared, isn't it?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you already, have `Audio` or lists of samples, then the answer is simple.
For `Sound` objects, you should convert them to `Audio` first.

```
music = Sound@SoundNote["A", 1.25, "Violin"]

(* Convert it to Audio *)
asaudio = Audio[music];

(* You can call Periodogram directly on audio without needing a list of samples *)
Periodogram[asaudio, ScalingFunctions -> "dB"]

(* ... and spectrogram *)
Spectrogram[asaudio]

(* ... and you get get data from the periodogram / spectrogram directly too *)
periodogramData = PeriodogramArray[asaudio]
spectrogramData = SpectrogramArray[asaudio];

(* You can get the sample rate and the samples like this *)
rate = AudioSampleRate[asaudio];
data = AudioData[asaudio];

(* and do your own DFT (note data can be stereo so I choose the first channel here) *)
channel1 = data[[1]];
four = Fourier[channel1];
powerSpectrumInDecibels = 20 Log10[Abs[four[[1 ;; Length[four]/2]]]];
ListPlot[powerSpectrum]
```

Comment: Thank u, it's very useful! Especially the use of AudioData in order to extract data (list of values) from Audio object.  As far as I understand, we can analogously use ImageData to extract data from an Image. 
Concerning Fourier command, it's still seems pretty inconvinient and even strange that we cannot apply Fourier directly on a image/Audio, but similar commands like Periodogramm, Spectrogramm, Wavelet can be apllied...
I'm telling that because I use another (more automized) ImageJ program. So I'd like to compare Wolfram results and ImageJ ones.

Comment: By the way, Spectrogramm/Periodogram can be applied on Sound object as well as on Audio object :)

Comment: @shamilkhal I didn't know that. I guess that makes it really easy then.